# Border outside of image and not on the padding

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my website:

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" style="margin: auto;border: 4px solid #93C69F;width: 100%;padding: 50px;" />
```

But the border is on the outside of the padding. I want the border to stay on the image.

Comment: so remove the padding, maybe use margin?

Comment: The CSS padding properties are used to generate space around an element's content, inside of any defined borders. So with padding this is not possible unless you create an empty element around the image that you apply the padding to. or use margin like @TemaniAfif suggested

Comment: You've asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Next time ask about your goal rather than your proposed solution. You'll spare us some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example where you can see the difference when using padding vs margin.

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#padded-image {
  border: 4px solid #93C69F;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 50px;
}

#margined-image {
  border: 4px solid #93C69F;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="padded-image" />
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="margined-image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the space between an element and its border, so in this case it is better to use margin instead of padding.